# How to write a sql query that splits a column information into individual rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I need to have my query return three rows that read as:

```
Theater        Screen       Begins 
cinemark 17    8            2015-11-21 10:50
cinemark 17    8            2015-11-21 12:10
cinemark 17    8            2015-11-21 2:23
```

I am getting a return of just one row that displays the 'begins' column with the date and all three show times. I'm not sure how to split the times into separate rows.

Here is my work:

```
SELECT 
NAME AS 'THEATER', TITLE AS 'TITLE', SCREEN_SCREEN_ID AS 'SCREEN', 
CONCAT(DATE, ' ',TIME) AS 'BEGINS'

FROM MOVIE_has_THEATER MT
INNER JOIN THEATER TH
ON MT.THEATER_THEATER_ID = TH.THEATER_ID

INNER JOIN MOVIE MO
ON MT.MOVIE_MOVIE_ID = MO.MOVIE_ID

INNER JOIN SCREEN SC
ON MT.SCREEN_SCREEN_ID = SC.SCREEN_ID 

WHERE TITLE = 'spectre' AND NAME = 'cinemark 17';
```

Comment: we need tables of data not pictures. I did an edit (rev2). Your last edit did a stomp over that. That table look helps people

Comment: You want the whole sql file for each of the tables im grabbing info from? Just seems like a lot.

Comment: don't remember saying that. Revert the edit to version 2. That is a table. Like what you gave and I formatted it. Then you wrote over it in subsequent edits

Comment: Incidentally, your table/column naming policy... Well, I'm glad it's not mine

Comment: show a few sample rows from your tables